(Unity) Skinned mesh renderer and mesh renderer look different
Hello, I have a problem in Unity.
In the image you can see two models, the left one with a skinned mesh renderer and the right one with just a mesh renderer. The left one is too shiny, and I need to fix that.
Can you help me?
Actual image
As I understand, the problem is with the normals or shading. I tried to change it in import settings, but it helped not.

isn't it more of a problem with the material.  ?
otherwise can you upload the 3D model somewhere ? i can check it out.
Did you btw use, URP or built-in ?
